# Firebase issue, multiple errors after upgrade

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase

After running the Firebase upgrade command, I tried to run my app in the emulator, and the following error messages appeared:

Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.24.0/lib/firebase_core.dart:19:7: Error: A function declaration needs an explicit list of parameters.
Try adding a parameter list to the function declaration.
await Firebase.initializeApp(
^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.24.0/lib/firebase_core.dart:19:15: Error: Expected '{' before this.
await Firebase.initializeApp(
^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.24.0/lib/firebase_core.dart:19:15: Error: Expected a declaration, but got '.'.
await Firebase.initializeApp(
^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.24.0/lib/firebase_core.dart:20:8: Error: Non-optional parameters can't have a default value.
Try removing the default value or making the parameter optional.
options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.24.0/lib/firebase_core.dart:21:2: Error: Expected a function body or '=>'.
Try adding {}.
);
^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.24.0/lib/firebase_core.dart:23:1: Error: Directives must appear before any declarations.
Try moving the directive before any declarations.
part 'src/firebase_app.dart';
^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.24.0/lib/firebase_core.dart:24:1: Error: Directives must appear before any declarations.
Try moving the directive before any declarations.
part 'src/firebase.dart';
^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.24.0/lib/firebase_core.dart:15:8: Error: Error when reading '/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.24.0/lib/firebase_options.dart': O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado.

import 'firebase_options.dart';
^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.24.0/lib/src/firebase.dart:9:7: Error: 'Firebase' is already declared in this scope.
class Firebase {
^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.24.0/lib/firebase_core.dart:19:7: Context: Previous declaration of 'Firebase'.
await Firebase.initializeApp(
^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.24.0/lib/firebase_core.dart:19:1: Error: Type 'await' not found.
await Firebase.initializeApp(
^^^^^
lib/main.dart:12:9: Error: Can't use 'Firebase' because it is declared more than once.
await Firebase.initializeApp(
^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.24.0/lib/firebase_core.dart:20:10: Error: Undefined name 'DefaultFirebaseOptions'.
options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.24.0/lib/src/firebase.dart:66:19: Error: Can't use 'Firebase' because it is declared more than once.
if (other is! Firebase) return false;
^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.24.0/lib/src/firebase.dart:75:26: Error: Can't use 'Firebase' because it is declared more than once.
String toString() => '$Firebase';
^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1159
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 49s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Could you 1) reformat these into a codeblock and 2) show us where you initialize firebase in your project?

Comment: @Jet.B.Pope consegui aqui, muito obrigado!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reinstalled flutter and rebuilt the code from scratch and instead of updating Firebase by running the command I just manually set the version number of the dependencies below to the latest one and ran the command `flutter pub get`, the in order to get updates made to ***pubsec.yaml***. The changed dependencies looked like this:

```
  cupertino_list_tile: ^0.2.1
  firebase_core: ^1.24.0
  cloud_firestore: ^3.5.1
  firebase_auth: ^3.11.2
  cloud_functions: ^3.3.9
```

That done, I ran my code again and everything worked as expected.